# express requests one at a time

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

In Express, is it possible to handle requests to a single route one at a time? I have a "checkout queue," and each time a checkout is created, stock is decreased. However, a simultaneous POST request to create a checkout checks the stock before stock is decreased in the first request, which causes overselling. Is there any way I can configure a route to accept requests one-at-a-time?

Comment: This is the wrong way to fix things.  What you have is a race condition in your code that uses the database where you get the value check it, then modify it in separate non-atomic operations.  If, instead, you change how you use your database to use atomic operations, then you can remove this race condition at the database access level and won't have to modify your route handling.  This would be the better way to fix things.  You don't show your actual code so we can't make more concrete recommendations.

Comment: FYI, you can sequence your route requests by creating a processing queue for incoming requests on this route, but as I said above, this isn't really the right way to solve things as you should just remove the race conditions in how you're using your database.  Plus, if you ever clustered your app or had other routes accessing the same data in the database, the queue wouldn't fully solve the problem anyway,